# proc upload local file

Tags: excel, sas, excel-2010

I'm trying to Proc Upload .xlsx files to my server, please can someone tell me what i'm doing wrong?

```
rsubmit;
filename locref %unquote(%str(%'("C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\")%'));

 Proc Upload
  infile=locref('*.xlsx') 
  outfile=%unquote(%str(%'("*.xlsx")%')) BINARY;
run;
endrsubmit;
```

Basically people will drop .xlsx files into a location with different file names and i'd like to upload them all onto the server.

Using SAS 9.3 64-bit with Windows 7 64-bit and Office 2010 32-bit.

Thank you

Comment: Why do you have so much messy quoting/unquoting in everything?

Comment: Also, this looks a lot like your previous question.  Why are you asking it again?  You don't specify what's not working here.

Comment: Noted @Joe just trying to improve on code created over years of colleagues leaving.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this example:

```
filename locref 'c:\';
rsubmit;
filename fref '/local/programs';
proc upload infile=locref('*.sas') 
           outfile=fref;
run;
endrsubmit;
```

Notice the `outfile=` option refers to a fileref that is an output *directory*, not a file. Also, in your code the first filename statement needs to come before `rsubmit;`, as in the example.

Your final code will be:

```
filename locref "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop";
rsubmit;
filename outref "<INSERT SERVER-SIDE DIRECTORY HERE>";

 Proc Upload
  infile=locref('*.xlsx') 
  outfile=outref BINARY;
 run;
endrsubmit;
```

N.B. Please replace the <> bit on line 3 with the directory on the remote server that you're uploading to. You've not quoted it in your original code, so I'm not sure where you want the files to go.

As @Joe said, there is no need for all the quoting/unquoting, it just makes the code harder to read and doesn't add any benefit in this case.

Comment: Thank you, the code i know is messy... i'm trying to build on/improve exisiting code from colleagues who have left the business [not helpful i know]! Is it possible to wildcard .xls and.xlsx? such as maybe ('*.xlsx','*.xls') ?

Comment: Try `'*.xls?'`, the question mark matches the second 'x' in 'xlsx' but also accepts blank. If that doesn't work, try `'*.xls*'`, the first solution is preferable.

Comment: Neither work, i get the following error for both "WARNING: No external files match the wildcard specification."

Comment: That's odd, best I can offer is to use two separate `PROC UPLOAD` steps, one with `'*.xls'` the other with `'*.xlsx'`. If both of those throw an error, double check the local directory for excel files.

Comment: Thanks @mjsqu.. both ('*.xlsx') and ('*.xls') work independently and also ('*') brings in anything from that folder. So i'll use these as required.